# Modify python code to return the product of the items on the list rather than the sum

Tags: python

Can anyone help to modify this small block of code i have to return the product of the items on the list rather than the sum.

This is the code:

```
def sum(seq):

    def add(x,y): return x+y

    return reduce(add, seq, 0)
```

Comment: Please share the full code. Its hard to understand what you passing in `seq`.

Comment: I think it seems pretty obvious from the way your code is structured... What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @PrashantKumar thats all the code i have? should there be more?

Comment: @Tomerikoo im having trouble understanding what it is im supposed to change about this code to get it to work

Comment: Just as you defined a function doing the `add` operation and passed it to `reduce`, do the same for multiplication...

Comment: @Tomerikoo okay i changed the + to a *, what code should i use to call it once i run the code

Comment: I have the program able to print the sum however i need it to return the product of the items
on the list rather than the sum.

Answer (score 1):

since youre already using reduce, just modify the function reduce uses:

```py
def product(seq):
    def mult(x, y): return x * y
    return reduce(mult, seq)
```

alternatively use a lambda instead of a function definition:

```py
reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, seq)
```

btw, for sum python has the builtin function sum: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

Comment: BTW, since Python 3.8, an equivalent of `sum` is available through the `math` module: [`math.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.prod)

Comment: i used this, and was able to produce the sum howver i need to return the product of the items
on the list rather than the sum.

Comment: @FawcettFawcett for me this works perfectly. `product([5, 5])  = 25`

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood your problem. Try this :

```
import functools
import operator
def multiplyList(inputList):
    return(reduce(operator.mul, inputList))
```

Comment: @laundmo Operator is an inbuilt library in Python and its sole purpose is to provide simple calculations. I would prefer and suggest using operator for operations that are provided in the Operator module.

Comment: @PrashantKumar why? they just do `a * b` in the source. i think it improves readability if you explicitly state what youre doing.

Comment: @laundmo The sight of a `lambda` expression (or a `def` in that matter), simply to make mult is much more confusing than a simple `operator.mul`. The fact that it is such a simple and obvious operation encourages to use `operator`.

Comment: @Tomerikoo the zen of python line 2: `Explicit is better than implicit.`

Comment: @laundmo implicit would be defining a function called `operate` and using that. `operator.mul` is pretty explicit. But I think this discussion is at a dead-end. Bottom-line is, this is a very simple use-case and both options are equally fine. In general, if you already have a built-in that does what you want, why not use it?

Comment: @Tomerikoo exactly my point. Also this guy is new to python it seems. Why troubling him with writing all the functions and looping and adding if it can be done by use of inbuilt methods.